# UICollectionView, cells are overlapped by Navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

Want to remove the space below the collectionView cells:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(300, 435)];
[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:20.0f];
[flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];

[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```